# Intersect overlapping entities and their attributes

Tags: qgis-3, overlapping-features, union, intersect

I have a shapefile containing 6 classes of polygons on QGis 3.14. Some of these polygons overlap each others, but they're not geometry errors or duplicates, just polygons with different attributes. However I need to have maximum one entity at any place. So, I'd like to obtain, for each overlapping area, a new entity containing the attributes of the polygons that overlap. I can't make an intersection on a single layer, and the union tool gives me two polygons with equal geometries.

What should I do ?

Comment: The SAGA Self-intersection tool did the job, thank you, merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 3, I can suggest paying attention to the SAGA's tool [Polygon Self-Intersection](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.4/shapes_polygons_12.html) that is placed in `Processing > Toolbox` under `SAGA > Vector Polygon tools > Polygon self-intersection`.

[image: saga]

Check also @Kazuhito's answers in this article [How to sum up values of overlapping polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/how-to-sum-up-values-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis/300321).

Maybe one day @xunilk will translate [his article](http://blogdezeka.blogspot.com/2019/01/determinando-polygon-self-intersection.html) in English.

---

**References:**

- [Finding polygon self-intersection with PyQGIS on QGIS 3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308033/finding-polygon-self-intersection-with-pyqgis-on-qgis-3-4)

Comment: Actually, @Kazuhito's answer using the aggregate tool with the geometry group-by function is perfect, after an union or even a spatial joint ! While the self intersection polygon tool deletes the other field's entries in intersecting feature's attribute tables. Thank you ;)